# Git ls-remote redirection

Tags: bash, git, redirect, console

when moving a git repository, the old url is still active but redirects to the new location.

`git remote-ls` lets me inspect all branches and tags. For automation purposes, would it be possible to check the new location of the redirect, so I could replace the old path with the new one?

Kind regards

Comment: That sounds to me more like a provider trick than a git feature. How do you _move_ a git repository? I ask so that I can understand what you are talking about.

Comment: i move it in the gitlab itself. Below settings I move it to a new location by transfering it. In the browser, I get a 302 redirect that displays the new location and I would like to receive it by a git command to extract it in the console

Comment: It sounds like you should write a wrapper that takes care of checking if there is a redirect to adjust a remote _if necessary_, then run the fetch/pull. Or you might try to see what happens if you set `http.followRedirects` to `false` and see what error code it uses or if the output can be parsed so that you could then react, adjust if there is a redirect and try again. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.15.4#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpfollowRedirects

Comment: So setting the `http.followRedirects` to `false` didn't change any behaviour (I changed it using `git config http.followRedirects false` and `git config --global http.followRedirects false`. Would you mind explaining a bit further about the wrapper idea, because I would have no idea how to start. I already googled if there is any console tool that I could use or to extract the traffic from a command, but I couldn't find anything

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102134/curl-check-redirect